How do I read the characters "ジュリアはとても可愛い、 そして彼女は赤い口紅を塗っている。" in Chinese Pinyin?
How do I read the characters "ジュリアはとても可愛い、 そして彼女は赤い口紅を塗っている。" in Chinese Pinyin?
I can only transcribe it as "ジュリアはとても kě' ài い、 そして bǐ nǚ は chì い kǒu hóng を tú っている," but I don't know the rest. How do I pronounce the other Chinese characters?

Are you asking how to read Japanese Kanji in Chinese? The question does not make it clear. The text is Japanese not Chinese - it is meant to be read in Japanese not in Chinese.

"Juria wa totemo kawaii, soshite kanojo wa akai kuchibeni o nutte iru". You may find the pronunciation through google translate. The language is Japanese,  the characters in it are Japanese Kanji. Because Chinese culture influences on Japanese culture, Japanese may look similar with Chinese. However they pronounces differently, e.g. 可愛 here should speak as kawaii. The other characters are kana. They are similar with English characters A-Z.

The Chinese characters in Japanese language have different pronunciations with Chinese language. So you may as well ask this question in Japanese Stack Exchange.
